# Gmail API PHP Client Library - How do you create a draft email with an attachment using the PHP client library?

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using Google's PHP client library to send calls to Gmail's API. Using those resources, I can create draft emails. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to use the client library to create draft emails with attachments. I've been reading everything I can find online for two weeks now, but I still don't have the answer.

This would seem to be straight forward. Anyone have the answer?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Thanks johncorser for the push in the right direction. With zetacomponents I was able to correctly build the message (after having failed for two weeks with PHPMailer and Mail_mime). Here's my final code:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'Google/autoload.php';
require 'Google/Client.php';
require 'Google/Service/Gmail.php';
require 'ezc/Base/base.php';

spl_autoload_register( array( 'ezcBase', 'autoload' ) );


//Get credential
$config = parse_ini_file('helpers/config.ini');

// Setup Google API Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($config['client_id']);
$client->setClientSecret($config['client_secret']);
$client->setRedirectUri($config['redirect_url']);
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify');

// Create GMail Service
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Check if user is logged out
if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

// Check if we have an authorization code; if so, use it
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $client->authenticate($code);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($url,FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
}

// Check if we have an access token in the session; if so, setup input form; if not, create auth URL
if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    echo "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <p>Your First Name: <input type='text' name='first' required></p>
        <p>Your Last Name: <input type='text' name='last' required></p>
        <p>Body (without any greeting):</p> <textarea rows='20' cols='100' name='body' required></textarea>
        <p>Select headshot (JPG, JPEG, PNG, or GIF) to upload: <input type='file' name='headshotToUpload' id='headshotToUpload' required></p>
        <p>Select resume PDF to upload: <input type='file' name='resumeToUpload' id='resumeToUpload' required></p>
        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Create Drafts'></p></form>";

} else {
    $loginUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

//If auth URL is set, create llink for user to login; otherwise, show logout link
if (isset($loginUrl)) {
    echo "<a class='login' href='" . $loginUrl . "'>First Click Here to Connect Through Google!</a>";
    } else {
    echo "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
}

//Once submit button is pressed, begin file upload process
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_hsfile = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["headshotToUpload"]["name"]);
    $target_cvfile = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["resumeToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;

    //Check if filenames already exist
    if (file_exists($target_hsfile)) {
        echo "Please rename your headshot before uploading.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if (file_exists($target_cvfile)) {
        echo "Please rename your resume before uploading.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    //Check that file types are permitted
    $hsFileType = pathinfo($target_hsfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($hsFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed for headshots.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    $cvFileType = pathinfo($target_cvfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($cvFileType != "pdf") {
        echo "Sorry, resumes must be in PDF format only.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    //Report on success or failure of upload
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your files were not uploaded. Please correct the noted error(s) and try again";
    } else {    
    // If everything is ok, try to upload file
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES["headshotToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_hsfile)) && ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resumeToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_cvfile)))) {
            echo "The files ". basename( $_FILES["headshotToUpload"]["name"]). " and ". basename( $_FILES["resumeToUpload"]["name"]). " have been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

    //Load data
    $agent_data = parse_ini_file('helpers/agents.ini', true);

    //Iterate through agencies


    foreach ($agent_data as $agency) {

        $mail = new ezcMail();

            $mail->addTo( new ezcMailAddress($agency['agent_email'], $agency['agent_first']." ".$agency['agent_last'] ));
            $mail->subject = "Submission of " . $_POST['first'] . " " . $_POST['last'] . " to " . $agency['agency_name'];
            $textpart = new ezcMailText("Dear " . $agency['agent_salut'] . " " . $agency['agent_last'] . "," . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . $_POST['body'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "Sincerely," . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . $_POST['first'] . " " . $_POST['last']);
            $fileAttachment1 = new ezcMailFile($target_hsfile);
            $fileAttachment2 = new ezcMailFile($target_cvfile);
            $mail->body = new ezcMailMultipartMixed( $textpart, $fileAttachment1, $fileAttachment2 );
            $message = $mail->generate();

        $msgbody = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();

            $msgbody->setRaw(rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($message), '+/', '-_'), '='));

        $draft = new Google_Service_Gmail_Draft();

            $draft->setMessage($msgbody);

        $service->users_drafts->create('me', $draft);

        unset($mail);
        unset($msgbody);
        unset($draft);

    }           

}       

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy IF you have the raw email message. I'd give something like this a try:

```
public function save_draft(Google_Service_Gmail $gmail, $raw_message, $gmail_thread_id = null)
{
    $postBody = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $postBody->setRaw(rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($raw_message), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    if ($gmail_thread_id)
        $postBody->setThreadId($gmail_thread_id);

    $draft = new Google_Service_Gmail_Draft();
    $draft->setMessage($postBody);
    return $gmail->users_drafts->create('me', $draft);
}
```

This function should create a draft, add that draft to whatever gmail thread you pass in, and return the result. The reason for that bizarre base64_encode business is because the gmail api expects a fairly specific encoding. You should be able to just include the attachment in the raw body.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. Two quick follow up questions: What is the purpose of inserting the thread? Is that in case the draft message is part of a thread? (In my specific case these all happen to be brand new messages.) Also, what's the best way to include the attachment in the raw body? I've experimented with PHPMailer and Mail_mime, but I felt like I never knew exactly what was happening when I was using those libraries, nor was I ever successful in creating a draft message with attachment that Gmail accepted.

Comment: That's correct, inserting the thread is only necessary if the draft is part of a thread. To include an attachment in the body, I like using a library like zetacomponents. [Here](http://zetacomponents.org/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html#sending-a-mail-with-html-inline-images-and-attachments) is the documentation for adding an attachment  to a message.

Comment: How to send draft? can we send draft?